# Working with arrays in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

I'm having a bit of a problem working with arrays in VBA, where the same would be trivial in (almost) any other language:

```
Public Function getArray() As MyType()
    'do a lot of work which returns an array of an unknown length'
    'this is O(N^2) or something equally intensive so I only want to call this once'
End Function

Public Sub doSomething()
    Dim myArray() As MyType
    Set myArray = getArray() 'FAILS with "Cannot assign to array error"'
End Sub
```

I think it might be that I need to define the length of the array in advance, or ReDim a dynamic array.  But I don't know the length of the returned array ahead of time, and I'd like to avoid calling the function twice:

```
Public Sub doSomething()
    Dim myArray(0 To UBound(getArray()) As MyType  'not entirely sure if this would work, but it involves calling getArray twice which I'd like to avoid
    Set myArray = getArray()
End Sub
```

In C# or Java the equivalent would be:

```
public MyType[] getArray(){
    //do some work and return an array of an unknown length
}

public void doSomething(){
    MyType[] myArray;
    myArray = getArray();  //one line and I don't need to define the length of array beforehand
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>When assigning arrays of **custom objects** in vba you need to pass them around as variants</strike>  I've included a full working sample.

Class Module named MyType:

```
Public Once As Integer
Public Twice As Integer
Public Thrice As Integer
```

Code in standard module:

```
Public Function getArray() As MyType()
Dim i As Integer, arr() As MyType
    'do a lot of work which returns an array of an unknown length'
    'this is O(N^2) or something equally intensive so I only want to call this once'
    For i = 0 To Int(Rnd() * 6) + 1
        ReDim Preserve arr(i)
        Set arr(i) = New MyType
        arr(i).Once = i
        arr(i).Twice = i * 2
        arr(i).Thrice = i * 3
    Next i
    getArray = arr
    MsgBox "Long process complete"
End Function

Public Sub doSomething()
Static myArray() As MyType
Dim i As Integer
    If UBound(myArray) = -1 Then
        myArray = getArray()
    End If
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        Debug.Print myArray(i).Once & vbTab & _
                    myArray(i).Twice & vbTab & _
                    myArray(i).Thrice
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub Test()
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 3
        Debug.Print "Run Number " & i & vbCrLf & String(10, "-")
        doSomething
        Debug.Print
    Next i
End Sub
```

The first time you run `doSomething` an array of random length will be generated and you will see a message box that says "Long process complete".  Subsequent calls to `doSomething` will re-use the array created the first time.

If you copy this code and just run the `Test` sub it will call `doSomething` three times. You will see the message box once and the output of `doSomething` in the immediate window three times.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could pass the array as a reference to the function like this:

```
Public Sub MyFunc(ByRef arr() As MyType)
  ...
End Sub


Dim myArr() as MyType
MyFunc myArr
```

Inside the function you can `ReDim` your array as wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to get rid of the `set` in Set `myArray = getArray()`

---

This behaves properly:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function getArray() As Integer()
    Dim test(1 To 5) As Integer
    test(1) = 2
    test(2) = 4
    getArray = test
End Function

Public Sub doSomething()
    Dim myArray() As Integer
    myArray = getArray()
    Debug.Print (myArray(2))
End Sub
```

Comment: This gives the "Object variable or With block variable not set" error, so I think the `Set` is required

Comment: This could be when your array is empty.

Comment: It works for me, without the set that is. What is myType? I have just used integers.

Comment: myType is a class I've defined in a class module.

Comment: And that's why this solution won't work for this particular case.  Working with custom objects complicates things in VBA.

Comment: @mwolfe02 Are you suggesting that this impossible?

Comment: No.  I've posted a working solution that deals with the custom object issue.

Answer (score 1):

**It is indeed possible to return an array from a function in VBA.** According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa189081.aspx):

> [Y]ou can also call a procedure that returns an array and assign that to another array. [ . . . ] Note that to return an array from a procedure, you simply assign the array to the name of the procedure.

So you just need to modify your existing code by removing `Set` from the assignment statement:

```
Public Function getArray() As MyType()
    'do a lot of work which returns an array of an unknown length'
    'this is O(N^2) or something equally intensive so I only want to call this once'
End Function

Public Sub doSomething()
    Dim myArray() As MyType
    myArray = getArray
End Sub
```

Comment: @mwolfe: I haven't personally tried it because I don't have access to Office right now, but it's exactly the same as that shown on MSDN (see the link included in my answer). I have little reason to assume that it won't work.

Comment: Mea culpa.  I went back and rechecked my own testing.  It appears that what you've got will indeed work.  I've also updated my own answer accordingly.

Comment: @mwolfe02, I wrote up a quick answer that looked very much like this, tested it, and then found this was already here. So I upvoted it as a correct solution and didn't bother to post mine. But yes it works.

Comment: @jtolle: I've since come to the same conclusion (see my comment immediately above yours).  I would delete my original comment if not for the fact that then all the follow-ups would no longer make sense.

Comment: @mwolfe: You were initially correct that arrays can be passed as a `Variant` instead of a specific type, but as you've since figured out, that's unrelated to the fact that you've created an object of a custom class. Thanks for testing the code and verifying that it does indeed work.